# How to perform significance test for a time dependent multiple linear regression equation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-regression

Let me describe the problem:

The general form of multi-variate regression model is given by $$Y = b_0 + b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + b_3x_3 +....+ eta$$
And the statistic to test the significance of coefficient say $b_2$ by student-t test, $$t = \frac{\hat{b_2}}{s.e.(\hat{b_2})} $$, s.e. is standard error.

However, in my developed model the regression model looks like $$Y(t) = b_1(t)x_1(t) + b_2(t)x_2(t)$$

The regression equation is time varying and with complex coefficients $b_1(t)$ and $b_2(t)$. I'm trying to determine the significance of $b_2(t)$ in the regression model and conducted some litertaure search, but was unable to find an appropriate test to perform significance tests for time-varying models. In this regard, could someone provide your advice/ keywords/ hints/ books to accomplish my tasks.